# Stack-Trac - List stackoverflow/serverfault/... questions that are related to your Trac tickets

Tags: app, python

**About**

This little app will look at the summary from the currently viewed Trac ticket and find related questions & answers on stackoverflow, or other stackexchange sites.

**Screenshot**
[stack-trac http://img705.imageshack.us/img705/7954/stacktrac.png](http://img705.imageshack.us/img705/7954/stacktrac.png)
([see full size](http://img705.imageshack.us/img705/7954/stacktrac.png))

**Installation**

Similar to a normal Trac plugin:
http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracPlugins

Full instructions:

1. Download the stack-trac source from http://code.google.com/p/stack-trac/source/checkout
2. cd to stacktrac-plugin
3. run python setup.py bdist_egg  (note: due to a bug, need to run: 'python setup.py develop' instead.  I have a fix but can't make it till I get back from work today)
4. copy dist/Stacktrac... to your_trac_project_folder/plugins
5. enable stacktrac in your trac.ini by adding the following

   [components]

   stacktrac.* = enabled

Configuring the site used by stacktrac:
add the following to your trac.ini:

```
[stacktrac]
site = http://www.stackoverflow.com
apiSite = http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0
```

where stackoverflow is replaced by the SE site you would like to query

This is what I would call a pre-alpha release to get some feedback.  Lots of hardening & new features for stack-trac's stack exchange api wrapper to come.  First time using Python. I must admit, I kinda like the language ;)

If the look and feel is deemed to be too similar to SE sites I'll gladly update it.

**License**

Apache 2

**Download**

http://code.google.com/p/stack-trac/source/checkout

**Code**

Written in Python, hosted @ google code
http://code.google.com/p/stack-trac

Comment: Isn't Python such a fun language to learn the first time you use it? I sure thought it was.

Comment: Minor note, you probably don't want the API version you're targeting to be configurable (the `apiSite` configuration).  Subsequent API version will contain numerous breaking changes, but 1.0 will be kept around for quite awhile.

Comment: @George yep, and I actually ended up enjoying the fact that code blocks are indicated by spacing.  Although I have mixed feelings on the mix of operators, global functions and method calls.  E.g., getting the length of a list is len(list) and not list.length()...  and using |= to append to structures...  I'm sure there are reasons for it, but I'm not educated enough about the language yet.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed a bug while installing this as en egg....  you may get a "template not found" error.  The work around is to run "python setup.py develop" instead of "python setup.py bdist_egg" and skip the copying steps.  I'll let you know once I find a fix for this.